# Is there any possibility to do XSS if there is str_replace?

Tags: php, xss, owasp

I'm studying Cross Site Scripting (XSS) Vulnerability, and here is a question:

Is there any possibility to do Cross Site Scripting by passing code through get parameter if there is str_replace "<" ?

```php
if (isset($_GET["username"])) {
    $user = str_replace("<", "", $_GET["username"]);
    echo "Your name is "."$user";
}
```

Could you still get `<b onmouseover=alert('Ha-Ha-Ha!')>click me!</b>` or `<script>alert('Ha-Ha-Ha')</script>` passed in so that the script executes?

Comment: Let me complete sidestep this question and ask why you're using a GET parameter for a user's name instead of using session management? When they logged in, PHP should have been able to match their login to their username, and you should not need $_GET here at all, you should be able to retrieve the current user's name from their active session just fine. And if you're asking about this "in general" (i.e. any GET value that gets echoed back into the page output) then it's a good idea to not make it look like you're asking about user data.

Comment: because I'm passing OWASP Vulnerable XSS here
https://github.com/OWASP/Vulnerable-Web-Application/blob/master/XSS/XSS_level5.php

Comment: That is not an answer. Does your example _hinge_ on the username? If so, this is nonsense and you should use session management for user information. Read [the PHP manual on sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.session.security.management.php) and put that practice. If not, and if it's just about $_GET variables that you copy into your PHP echo/prints, change your post to reflect that. Right now you're giving a _very specific example_ that has a solution that is entirely unrelated to your question. Which makes this a bad question: update your post to clarify what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The charset isn't specified so there could be some ways of bypassing the filter using different encodings. In older browsers, it was possible to use UTF-7 as described at: http://michaelthelin.se/security/2014/06/08/web-security-cross-site-scripting-attacks-using-utf-7.html

Answer (score -2):

Use `htmlspecialchars()` method

- this function what you need

```
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

- you can check w3schools handling form
  https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp
- also use post method it's secure more than get

Comment: The point is how to overcome  str_replace("<", "", $_GET["username"]) in order to do XSS.

Comment: - sorry i haven't experience in working with xss but what i think that now there's too many ways to save your server from XSS so it's hard to find a way to do that because you are not controling the server - i hope you find a way

Comment: 1. This does not protect against all forms of xss, and trimming has nothing to do with xss, or inputs in general. 2. This should not be run on input, xss is an output encoding problem. 3. post is not "more secure" than get with regard to xss.